# Node.js App - Multiple services in a single directory

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've built a node.js which acts as my worker. I now need to create an API that interacts with this worker. I could add that code in the codebase as the worker, however would like to seperate it so as not to put too much strain on the worker.

The piece I'm unsure about it is both the worker and API will have functions and node_module in common. How do I therefore managed this? Do I have on main node_modules folder, then have my seperate processes in there?

At the moment the folder structure looks like this:

```
.
+-- .gitignore
+-- Worker
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- src/index.ts
|   +-- eslintrc.js
+-- API
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- src/index.ts
|   +-- eslintrc.js
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a package.json in the root directory. That way node_modules would be also in root folder and both API and Worker would share node_modules.